# Returning struct with const char* property

Tags: c++

In this wrapper method, I return a `DN_OPstruct`, which has two `const char*` properties: `TargetNode_Identifier` and `Name`. For `p/invoke`, I have to stay with `const char*` - Type, `std::string` won't work:

```
DN_OPstruct getDnOperationIntern(const char* charGuid){
    DN_OPstruct op;
    UA_OPstruct _op;     
    _op = GetOPData(charGuid);
    op.direction = _op.direction;
    op.Name = _op.Name.toUtf8(); 
    op.TargetNode_Identifier = _op.TargetNode_Identifier.toUtf8();
    op.TargetNode_NamespaceIndex = _op.TargetNode_NamespaceIndex;
    op.Type_of_OP = _op.Type_of_OP;
    return op ;
}
```

As I read, you have to `strcpy` `const char*`s . Without such help, the pointers of the properties will lose thier reference and I get false properties. Example for strcpy:

```
strcpy(new char[output.size()], output.c_str());
```

How can implement this in my method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'object deletion at the end'? `op` is going out of scope, as well as `_op` what exactly do you want to achieve? IF you want to copy members from `_op` to `op`, the behaviour depends on the behaviour of the types involved.

Comment: Recommend dropping either C or C++ tag.

Comment: Why should it be `const`, is it a requirement?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `toUtf8()` returns a `const char*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't implement it in your method - instead, you should implement it in a separate function, and use it in all places where you need to make a copy of a string:

```
char *copyCString(const string& s) {
    char *res = new char[s.size()+1]; // Add 1 for null terminator
    strcpy(res, s.c_str());
    return res;
}
```

Now you can use this function to make copies as needed:

```
op.Name = copyCString(_op.Name); 
op.TargetNode_Identifier = copyCString(_op.TargetNode_Identifier);
```

You could start with `const char*`, too:

```
char *copyString(const char* s) {
    char *res = new char[strlen(s)+1]; // Add 1 for null terminator
    strcpy(res, s);
    return res;
}
```

Now you call it like this:

```
op.Name = copyString(_op.Name.toUtf8()); 
op.TargetNode_Identifier = copyString(_op.TargetNode_Identifier.toUtf8());
```

Of course you are responsible for deleting the copies when you are done:

```
delete[] op.Name;
delete[] op.TargetNode_Identifier;
```

It would be a good idea to define a function for this, too:

```
void freeCopiedString(char *s) {
    delete[] s;
}
```

Comment: In this case: I'd define a special function (as you've done) for creating the strings, _and_ a special function for freeing them.  You don't want to count on your client code using `delete []`/`::operatr delete()`/`free`, depending on the allocation method you've used; you allocate, so you want to free yourself (using whichever method you decide to allocate).

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight I have one question for deleting the copies: where can i call the delete function? in my main method, I set the properties of a `DN_OPstruct`, at the end i return `op`as seen in my SO question. If i would call the delete function before `return op;` the properties would obviously were deleted

Comment: @Pepelee That's the unfortunate part: the caller that gets `DN_OPstruct` from your function has to call `freeCopiedString` when he is done with the `struct`.